# In Business Catalyst, where are the blogs files located?

Tags: file, backup, blogs, business-catalyst

I want to do a backup of my blogs in business catalyst, but i can only import. There is no export features.

So I want to go on the business catalyst server directly to get the files, but I can't find any of them, even when doing a 'Find all in folder' search.

Where are the blogs files ? I can actually see my blogs on the business catalyst site so they must be somewhere, right ?

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no immediate access to an export of the Blog module in BC. Also the posts are saved server side in a database, so you will not find them in FTP as they are not filed that exist on the site.  Both these points means it won't be simple to get them out.

The only thing you can do is put all the posts out into an RSS feed and the download the XML as a backup. Some more of this method is explained on the Adobe forums - https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1002301

Comment: Thank you Deanmv, you get the answer so far. I'm really wondering where are the blogs stored really. Do they store it on secured servers ? If so, why ? Can they offer a solution for migration or backup without working around a xml of your blogs.

Comment: I imagine they are stored in BC databases as it is an inbuilt module from Adobe so they can control the fields/database structure. What I would recommend is re-creating it as a WebApp as then you can create the fields and you have full export and import capabilities through CSV

Comment: Ho yeah, can web app do the job for blogs ? Not sure yet how that works, will investigates right away. Thank you !